# express app - create table from JSON data. Change background of failed data

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am trying to create a simple express app that renders a table from a JSON file.  I am currently able to generate an HTML table with JSON data.  Value from the JSON file is either a passed or failed.  If the value is failed I would like to change the cell to a red background.

I am able to create the table but I am having an issue accessing the "failed" vaules.   I have tried nested for loops to value but keep getting error in my nested loop that data is undefined.

Looking for ideas on how to select the values that show failed then how to update the background of the table cell.

**JSON DATA**

```
[
{
    "DC":  "SV07DC1",
    "Connectivity":  "Passed",
    "Advertising":  "Passed",
    "FRS":  "Passed",
    "DFSR":  "Passed",
    "KCCEvent":  "Passed",
    "K.R.Holders":  "Passed",
    "Mach.Acct":  "Passed",
    "NetLogons":  "Passed",
    "Obj.Repl":  "Passed",
    "Repl":  "Passed",
    "RidMgr":  "Passed",
    "Services":  "Passed",
    "SystemLog":  "Failed",
    "VerifyRef":  "Passed",
    "Loc.Check":  "Passed",
    "Intersite":  "Passed"
},
{
    "DC":  "SV07DC2",
    "Connectivity":  "Passed",
    "Advertising":  "Passed",
    "FRS":  "Passed",
    "DFSR":  "Passed",
    "KCCEvent":  "Passed",
    "K.R.Holders":  "Passed",
    "Mach.Acct":  "Passed",
    "NetLogons":  "Passed",
    "Obj.Repl":  "Passed",
    "Repl":  "Passed",
    "RidMgr":  "Passed",
    "Services":  "Passed",
    "SystemLog":  "Failed",
    "VerifyRef":  "Passed",
    "Loc.Check":  "Passed",
    "Intersite":  "Passed"
}
]
```

**app.js file**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));

 var data; 

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
 fs.readFile('adhealth.json', 'utf8', function (err, contents) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        data = JSON.parse(contents)
        console.log(data.length);
    }
})
res.render("index", { data: data })
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("server started");
})
```

Finally here is my front end table data page

```
<html>

<body>


<h1 class="text-center">Table data</h1>



<table class="table table-dark table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
    <thead class="">
        <tr>
            <th>DC</th>
            <th>Connectivitiy</th>
            <th>Advertising</th>
            <th>FRS</th>
            <th>DFSR</th>
            <th>KCCEvent</th>
            <th>K.R Holders</th>
            <th>Mach.Acct</th>
            <th>NetLogons</th>
            <th>OBJ.Repl</th>
            <th>Repl</th>
            <th>RidMgr</th>
            <th>Services</th>
            <th>SystemLog</th>
            <th>VerifyRef</th>
            <th>Loc.Check</th>
            <th>Intersite</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <% data.forEach(function(dc) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= dc["DC"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["Connectivity"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["Advertising"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["FRS"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["DFSR"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["KCCEvent"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["K.R.Holders"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["Mach.Acct"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["NetLogons"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["Obj.Repl"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["Repl"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["RidMgr"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["Services"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["SystemLog"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["VerifyRef"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["Loc.Check"] %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= dc["Intersite"] %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to Your **td** elements

```
   <td <% if ( dc["SystemLog"] === "Failed" ){ %>
        style="background-color:red;"
        <% } %> >
        <%= dc["SystemLog"] %>
    </td>
```

**if** statement check if returned value is equal to "Failed" and if it is then we paste style to that html element

and... You can make this code little bit shorter

```
<table class="table table-dark table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
    <thead class="">
        <tr>
            <% for ( key in data[0] ) { %>
                <th><%= key %></th>
            <% } %>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <% data.forEach(function(dc) { %>
        <tr>
            <% for ( key in dc ) { %>
                <td <% if ( dc[key]==="Failed" ) { %>
                    style="background-color: red;"
                    <% } %>>
                <%= dc[key] %>
                </td>
            <% } %>
        </tr>
    <% }) %>
</table>
```